# Bootstrap 4 toggle menu "dropdown" (only in mobile view)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple navigation bar at the very top of my site with two links only.  When the view becomes mobile (tablet and/or mobile), those links disappear and the menu "hamburger" icon shows. However, when I click it, nothing shows.  I want both my links to show when I click the menu icon.

[image: Desktop view]
[image: Mobile view]

```css
/* Registration Navbar */

.registration-navbar {
  background-color: #8ABE57;
  height: 45px;
}

.registration-navbar ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.registration-navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #31353D;
}

.navbar-dark,
.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark registration-navbar">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse my-auto" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mi Cuenta</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registrarme</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove height : 45px from .registration-navbar and that will solve the problem .

```
/* Registration Navbar */

.registration-navbar {
  background-color: #8ABE57;
}

.registration-navbar ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.registration-navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #31353D;
}

.navbar-dark,
.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```